# Laravel : make one form for both create and edit

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 forms like usual (edit.blade.php + create.blade.php) 
i have one Model $product which has many relations for example `$product->product_meta->price`

for a direct value $product->name i have added this within the forms and works like charm with no any kind of problems :

1- Within the create I added the following :

```
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old('name_ar') ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

2- Within the edit I also added the following and it works just fine

```
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old('name_ar') ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

When it comes to a relation, these aren't working:

```
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old('product_meta.price') ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old(['product_meta']['price']) ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

any ideas ? !

Comment: I would use if/else to see if the relation (product_meta->price) is set.  If it is, pass it do old(), if not, simply default to an empty string.

Comment: I like this approach (works with Laravel 5, too) which reuses the same form both for edit and create: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Answer (score 1):

I do that on some models, but usually prefer to avoid it just because many times the logic is different on create and update.

Anyway the following doesn't work if you haven't that field in the view.

```
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old('product_meta.price') ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

old() refers to a input with that name, so if the field is named "name_ar" you can't get the old value of that using 'product_meta.price'.

But old() also accepts a second argument as a fallback, so you could check for the old input, then if doesn't exist (no submit has been done) set the value with the relation data like that:

```
{!! Form::text('name_ar', old('name_ar', ( isset($product) ? $product->product_meta->price ,'') ) ,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

The above will look for the old input named 'name_arr' on the last submit, then if it's not found (you haven't submitted yet), will look if the variable $product is set (so you're editing), than if it's not set set the value empty '' (you're creating)

Hope this help

Cheers